# Find the equation of a line tangent to $y=3x^2-4x$ and parallel to the line $2x-y+3=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equation of a line tangent to $y=3x^2-4x$ and parallel to the line $2x-y+3=0$ number $3$ on the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf4km.jpg)

Comment: You got an answer now (for free). Next time, please share some thoughts with us as to how you tried the problem, this is not an online homework site

Answer (score 2):

we have $$y'(x)=6x-4$$ and since the Tangent line is parallel to $$y=2x+3$$ we get
$$y'(x)=6x-4=2$$ thus $$x=1$$ for $$x=1$$ we get $$y=-1$$ and our Tangent line has the equation
$$y=2x-3$$